INSERT failed because the following SET options have incorrect setting
Перед тем, как задать этот вопрос, естественно гуглил. Сделал всё, как в рекомендациях — не помогает.
Ситуация такая: есть некая система в организации (процедуры на MS SQL и т. д.). Потребовалась модернизация: нужен запуск джоба после вставки новой записи в таблицу. Сделал триггер — стало появляться сообщение об ошибке в настройках, как показано на картинке:

Выставил все "магические 7" настройки, как описано в статьях — не помогает:
SET ANSI_NULLS ON;
SET ANSI_PADDING ON;
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON;
SET ARITHABORT ON;
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON;
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT ON;
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;

Точнее из-под SSMS запускаешь ту же хранимую процедуру, которая делает вставку в таблицу, — прокатывает, а когда выполняешь это же действие, но из-под системы, — ошибка:

INSERT failed because the following SET options have incorrect setting...

Без триггера работает. Как быть, что делать? Без триггера никак...

А вот это "выставил все настройки" это где вы проделали? По идее это либо приложение должно выставлять после установки соединения, либо прямо в хранимку (или триггер) в прологе нужно вставить.

Прямо в триггере в прологе и в самом есть.

А вставка только через процедуру? Не ad-hoc какой-нибудь из приложения генерится? Тогда может быть в процедуре попробовать в прологе тоже указать? Вероятно у триггера свой отдельный контекст от запроса, который его вызывает.

Да, вероятно правильнее будет выставлять опции не в триггере, а в том месте, в контексте которого происходит INSERT.

"В прологе" я имел ввиду в теле ХП/триггера (обычно в начале где-то после BEGIN).
